# Differentiate the Function: $h(x)=\ln\ (x\sqrt{x^2-1})$

Tags: calculus

$h(x)=\ln\ (x\sqrt{x^2-1})$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1+1(x^2-1)(2x)}{2(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{1}{y}\ (y)=(y)\frac{2(2x^3-2x)}{2(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}$

$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac {\ln\ (x\sqrt{x^2-1}\ 4x^3-4x}{2(x+\sqrt{x^2-1})}$

Using the following steps in Logarithmic Differentiation:

1) Take the natural logarithms of both sides of an equation y=(x) and use the Laws of Logarithms to simplify

2) Differentiate implicitly with respect to x

3) Solve the resulting equation for y' .

Why is this method useful? The books indicated this how we should solve these problems, but I found it confusing

Am I right?

Comment: Logarithmic differentiation is useful to avoid lots of product/quotient rules, turning them instead into sums and differences.  It is not useful here.  What you have done is not logarithmic differentiation, it is the derivative of an expression that happens to contain a log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you are not right. Here are graphs of the actual derivative and of your proposed derivative.

[image]

As you can see, they are very different.

Here is a better way to do the problem.
$$\begin{align}
h(x) & = \ln(x\sqrt{x^2-1}) \\
 & = \ln x+ \ln((x^2-1)^{1/2}) \\ 
 & = \ln x+\frac 12\ln(x^2-1) \\
\frac {dh}{dx} & = \frac 1x+\frac 12\cdot\frac{1}{x^2-1}\cdot 2x \\ 
 & =\frac 1x+\frac{x}{x^2-1}
\end{align}$$

You can combine that into one fraction, if you like. Note that this is defined for $-1<x<0$ and $0<x<1$ while the derivative is not, so my formula is actually an extension of the answer. The correct answer would say "for $x<-1$ or $1<x$" or perhaps "for $|x|>1$."

[image]

---

The time to do "logarithmic differentiation" is when you have many functions multiplied and divided and exponentiated together, *not* when you have a logarithm in the function. Examples include

$$y=x^x$$
$$y=(\sin x)^{\tan x}$$
$$y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{(x-3)^4(x^2+1)}{(2x+5)^3}}$$

Comment: When do I use the method recommended by the book?1) Take the natural logarithms of both sides of an equation y=(x) and use the Laws of Logarithms to simplify

2) Differentiate implicitly with respect to x

3) Solve the resulting equation for y' .

Comment: @SunnyBlack: See the addition to my answer.

Comment: @SunnyBlack The idea of logarithmic differentiation is usefull if the function contains lots of products and divisions, assuming that the function does not start with $ln$ In that case you take the $ln$ on both sides to perform your method. In this case, the function already starts with an $ln$ so start expanding the function using log laws

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln\ (x\sqrt{x^2-1})=\ln x+\ln\sqrt{x^2-1} = \\\ln x+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2-1) = \ln x+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x+1)+\frac{1}{2}\ln(x-1)$$ Taking a derivative of an ln that contains only linear terms, can't be that hard.